# what are channels in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use a logging mechanism as follows:

```
log_handler:
    class: %monolog.handler.stream.class%
    arguments: [ %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.yourFileName.log ]


logger:
class: %monolog.logger.class%
    arguments: [ nameOfLoggingChannel ]
    calls: [ [pushHandler, [@log_handler]] ]
```

however my app is crapping out parsing the "nameOfLoggingChannel". What is that? Can someone provide some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a name. It will be included in the messages logged by that logger. Quoting from [the docs](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/usage.md#leveraging-channels):

> Channels are a great way to identify to which part of the application a record is related. This is useful in big applications (and is leveraged by MonologBundle in Symfony2). You can then easily grep through log files for example to filter this or that type of log record.
>
> Using different loggers with the same handlers allow to identify the logger that issued the record (through the channel name) by keeping the same handlers (for instance to use a single log file).

```
<?php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

// Create some handlers
$stream = new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/my_app.log', Logger::DEBUG);
$firephp = new FirePHPHandler();

// Create the main logger of the app
$logger = new Logger('my_logger');
$logger->pushHandler($stream);
$logger->pushHandler($firephp);

// Create a logger for the security-related stuff with a different channel
$securityLogger = new Logger('security');
$securityLogger->pushHandler($stream);
$securityLogger->pushHandler($firephp);
```